# What is the best practice to manual build software on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, compiling

`apt` is great, this is also why many people choose Debian-based systems; however, there're some times that we need to build some software manually. (For example, for a newer version).

I create a folder `~/apps/` and put all the sources I downloaded here. This sounds like a port tree in FreeBSD. So what is the best practice to build and manage manual built software?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [CheckInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall). Essentially, instead of using

```
sudo make install
```

you can use

```
sudo checkinstall
```

This installs software as packages managed by dpkg, which means that you can easily uninstall it with

```
sudo dpkg -r packagename
```

Comment: Thank you! `checkinstall` is an interesting package. Will apt system update the software I installed via checkinstall after an even newer version of the software shows up in the apt repository?

Comment: @Nick Good question! When you install via `checkinstall`, you have to pick a name to install under. I presume that if you choose a name that is different to the repo version, it would not get updated. I'm unsure as to what would happen if you picked the same name, but I _suspect_ that `apt-get` would upgrade it. I can't find a definitive answer to this, but you could easily test it by installing an old version, then trying to `apt-get upgrade`. In general though, I find that if a repo lags once, it lags forever.